# Running multiple build agents and deployment agents that service different Organisations on one Server

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

Is it possible to run multiple Azure Self-hosted build/deploy agents and multiple deployment agents on one server?  Also, can these agents service more than one organisation or even multiple Azure AD Tenants?

I do realise the consequences with the server straining under IO bottlenecks and the like, these agents will probably never have to manage more than 3 projects being build and/or deployed at a time, but the sources can be from different projects in different organisations or possibly Tenants.

I have deployed my Deployment Agents to the servers and they function fine with a Microsoft-hosted build agent (my question is about ONE of these servers, it would apply to all of them eventually), but I am afraid to now start deploying the build agents to the same servers now.

Comment: Yes this is possible (had this setup a while ago) but i'd suggest to use a different server for each organisation anyway

Comment: Thank you @D.J., but have one web-server cluster, that has to service all our company's web applications, but they development teams are from different teams across the country that work on separate projects, so I was thinking of creating these geographical teams as organisations in Azure DevOps.  Is there a better way to separate them, if they all have to publish to one set of servers?

Comment: so the organisations are basically from the same company ? in that case you can don't need different servers per organisation..... i don't know how big your company is but i'd use the same organisation for all teams and separate them by projects and security-groups

Comment: @D.J. we're around 100 developers across 4 geographical locations working on about 50 active projects, with 1 web server cluster.  

I think your proposal is fantastic!  Managing one organisation, with all projects in one place, and 'hidden' to users with user groups makes so much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is very Do-able and is actually really cost-effective if you do not have continuous deployments or your virtual machine has the IO capacity to handle the planed traffic.

Understand the basics of an Agent. What exactly happens when you host a Windows Agent is that it creates a Windows Service which would run internally a separate new process and perform the actions for the agent.

Since these are independent processes, they are not at all impacted by the operations of other agents. As long as you are not trying to access the same files/resources this approach is actually a great approach and we should surely try this.